# How to convert the x509.get_pubkey() to hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, public-key-encryption, tls1.2

I need to extract the public-key from x509 certificate. I used this script:

```
import socket, ssl
import OpenSSL

hostname='www.google.com'
port=443

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
ssl_sock.connect((hostname, port))
ssl_sock.close()
print("ssl connection Done")

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((hostname, port))

# OpenSSL
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)

print(x509.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key())
```

The value I get from `.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()` is this:

```
<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x0000021B75346908>
```

But I need the public-key in hexadecimal format. i.e. RSA modulus.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be quite late for you, but useful for others.

`print OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,x509.get_pubkey())`